# Accessing Data from one function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My aim is to access the value of my drop-down from my getData function....The data correctlys shows on the run function but how can i pass that data down to the getData() function??

```
                      <select class="form-control" id="year" onChange="run()"
                            name="year" ng-model="year" >
                         <option value="-1">All Months</option>
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">Feburary</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                </select>
                <script>
                function run() {
                    var e = document.getElementById("year").value;
                    console.log(e)
                }
                function getdata(run) {
                    run();
                }
              </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to return data from the `run()` function first. Try it like this:

```
function run(){ 
    return document.getElementById("year").value;
}

function getdata() {
    var e = run();
    console.log(e)
}
```

Or, you can pass data to `getdata()` function directly like this:

```
function run(){ 
    var e =  document.getElementById("year").value;
    getdata(e);
}

function getdata(dataFromRun) {
    console.log(dataFromRun);
}
```

I hope it helps.